# How can i consume a rest API that is already deployed on an apache tomcat server (POST)

Tags: spring-boot, rest, tomcat, swagger-ui

so this Rest API is for analytic results and it is deployed on a server , and works by (POST),
the p parameters : the  id and the date
the Response body is an objectResponse(jason)
my question is how can i consume this Rest API without having an entity class on my local project

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried working with Resttemplate witch let you get data from an external  API by getting the new http but  the problem is that all the rest apis are (POST) they take params and get you the analytics results (Json)

Comment: Not sure what all solutions you have tried but as far as I understand the question , If your rest api is returning a model (or Entity), a good solution is to create that entity at consumer side, so that your POJO gets mapped with the response. This also ensures a rest API contract.